# Seamless looping on Chrome using Web Audio API

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

I am having trouble getting seamless looping to work in Chrome using the Web Audio API.  The delay is slight (< 100ms) but very noticeable.  The files I have tested are m4a and wav.  They loop seamlessly in Safari 6, but not in Chrome 23.  I am using sample code here: http://www.w3.org/2011/audio/wiki/Basic-Examples#Looping_Sounds_Without_Gaps